# Escape character issue inside SQL Agent job step

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, sql-server-agent

I'm having an issue when trying to use the sp_msforeachdb undocumented procedure in an agent job step. Here is my script to create the job step:

```
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Weekly Blob Backup',
    @step_name = N'Run Backup',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'EXEC sp_msforeachdb '' BACKUP DATABASE [?] TO URL = ''''http://urlgoeshere.blob.core.windows.net/subfolder/SIMSPROCESSOR1_'''' + ''''?'''' + ''''_'''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 112) + ''''.bak'''' WITH COMPRESSION, CREDENTIAL = ''''SQLBlobStorageCredential''''''',
    @retry_attempts = 0,
    @retry_interval = 0
```

When executing I get the following:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)  Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I've been successful when re-writing this to backup a single database. Clearly something isn't right with the escaping of characters, but when I put the 'Exec sp_msforeachdb' statement inside a PRINT() and execute that, everything looks right.

Comment: What happens when you try to EXECUTE the 'Exec sp_msforeachdb' statement directly in SSMS?

Comment: After removing the extra sets of apostrophes that are no longer required (from being inside the @command parameter string), SQL Server outputs the same errors seen above, once for each database.

Comment: I think maybe all those places where you have 4 single quotes maybe you only need 2.   Now that you know the error isn't because of the job, you can play with it in SSMS until it executes, and then the same string should work fine in the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out BACKUP DATABASE doesn't like when you concatenate a string in the TO URL clause. This worked:

```
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Weekly Blob Backup',
    @step_name = N'Run Backup',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'EXEC sp_msforeachdb ''DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(500) = N''''http://urlgoeshere.blob.core.windows.net/simsstorage/'''' + SUBSTRING(@@SERVERNAME, CHARINDEX(''''\'''', @@SERVERNAME, 1) +1, 100) + ''''_'''' + N''''?'''' + N''''_'''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 112) + N''''.bak'''' BACKUP DATABASE [?] TO URL = @url WITH COMPRESSION, CREDENTIAL = ''''SQLBlobStorageCredential''''''',
    @retry_attempts = 0,
    @retry_interval = 0
```